# Show that $\sum\limits_{m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2} \to t$-a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Use Borel-Cantelli to show that$\sum\limits_{m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2} \to t$-a.s. by computing $E(\sum\limits_{m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2} - t)^{2}$

where $ \Delta _{m,n}=B_{\frac{mt}{2^{n}}}-B_{\frac{(m-1)t}{2^{n}}}$ where $(B_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ is a brownian motion

I am struggling to compute to compute $E(\sum\limits_{m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2} - t)^{2}$:

$E(\sum\limits_{m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2} - t)^{2}=E((\sum\limits_{m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2})^{2}-2t\sum\limits_{m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2}+t^2)=E((\sum\limits_{m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2})^{2})-2tE(\sum\limits_{m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2})+t^2$

I do not know how to continue with the first term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that $$\mathbb E\left(\sum\limits_{1\leq m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2} - t\right)^{2}= \sum_{m_1=1}^{2^n}\sum_{m_2=1}^{2^n}\mathbb E\left[\left(\Delta _{m_1,n}^{2} - t2^{-n}\right)\left(\Delta _{m_2,n}^{2} - t2^{-n}\right)\right].$$
If $m_1\neq m_2$, the term $\mathbb E\left[\left(\Delta _{m_1,n}^{2} - t2^{-n}\right)\left(\Delta _{m_2,n}^{2} - t2^{-n}\right)\right]$ is zero due to the independence of increments of a Brownian motion. We thus obtain 
$$\mathbb E\left(\sum\limits_{1\leq m \leq 2^{n}} \Delta _{m,n}^{2} - t\right)^{2}= \sum_{m =1}^{2^n} \mathbb E\left[\left(\Delta _{m ,n}^{2} - t2^{-n}\right)^2\right].$$
To conclude, observe that $\Delta_{m,n}$ has a centered normal distribution with variance $t2^{-n}$.

Comment: I understand that the terms $(\Delta_{m_{1},n}^{2}-t2^{-n})$ and $(\Delta_{m_{2},n}^{2}-t2^{-n})$ are independent by virtue of Brownian. But since we're altering the increments, for example squaring the increments and subtracting $-t2^{-n}$, I do not see why $E(\Delta_{m_{1},n}^{2}-t2^{-n})=0=E(\Delta_{m_{2},n}^{2}-t2^{-n})$ when $m_{1}\neq m_{2}$

Comment: The expectation of $\Delta_{m_1,n}^2$ is $t2^{-n}$.